# Repeat string in apache velocity

Tags: velocity, jetbrains-ide

I want to define a custom file template for my PhpStorm IDE and want to use `#set` directive to define a string variable based on `$NAME`

the name is `foo/bar/baz` I want to count `/` and create  `$RELATIVE_PATH` variable `../../../`

How can I create `$RELATIVE_PATH` based on `$NAME`?

Comment: I have doubts that `$NAME` will have path bits in it. AFAIK it has only the actual file name... Although I may be completely wrong here as I have not tried entering path part in my tests.

Comment: Anyway: https://i.imgur.com/eN1Y5CM.png -- this **very old and definitely sub-optimal code** (can be written better) can convert `foo_BAR_meow` into `FooBarMeow`. You can apply similar approach for your needs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Java `String.replaceAll()` method:

```
#set($RELATIVE_PATH = "$NAME.replaceAll('[^/]+', '..')/")
```